# Select a record with non-null value columns

Tags: mysql, sql

i stuck in this problem. If i have a table like this:

```
----------------------------------------
ID |  field1 | field2 | field3| field4 |
----------------------------------------
1  |   1     |   0    |    1  |  0     |
----------------------------------------
2  |   0     |   1    |    0  |  1     |
----------------------------------------
```

I want to write a query that select a record with only columns equal= 1 like
1. where ID = 1

```
 ---------------------
ID |  field1 | field3 
----------------------
1  |   1     |   1
```

2. Where ID = 2

```
 ---------------------
ID |  field2 | field4 
----------------------
2  |   1     |   1
```

Can you guys suggest or give me an advice,  how to make it?

Thank you so much for taking times to read about my question.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, SQL doesn't do that, conditionally returning columns at run time.

The set of columns to be returned is determined at the time the SQL statement is parsed and prepared. It can't be dynamically changed at run time.

To get the results as shown, we would need two different queries

```
SELECT t.id, t.field1, t.field3
  FROM mytable t 
 WHERE ...
```

and

```
SELECT t.id, t.field2, t.field4
  FROM mytable t 
 WHERE ...
```

We can supply aliases for expressions in the SELECT list, but again, those have to specified in the SQL text; those can't be altered at execution time.

```
 SELECT t.id, 1 AS field2, 1 AS field4 
   FROM mytable t 
  WHERE ...
```

But we still would need different SQL text to return field1 and field3.

---

Seems like there are 2^4 (1+4+6+4+1) possible combinations of field 1..4 that could be populated. A total of 16 possible SELECT lists.

We could run a prequery, to find out which fieldN should be returned, and use the result from that query to formulate the text of a second query.

But the rigmarole needed to do that doesn't seem warranted.

Comment: It would be possible to craft a query that would return two columns, one with the `id` value, and a second column as a string, that contains a comma (or other delimiter) separated list...  e.g.  `'field1,field3'`.  We could get that returned as a string value, a single column, with whatever alias e.g. `foo` we assigned as the column heading.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use WHERE condition to SELECT values. considering the table name as Table1.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1
```

If you want to select from multiple IDs you can use IN clause.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID IN (1,2)
```

if you want just Field1, Field3 then just mention them in the SELECT query. You don't need *, which corresponds to all the fields.

```
SELECT Field1, Field3 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1
```

Comment: thank you so much , but If using "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1"  that will return all column of id = 1, the expected result that i want is just only field 1 and field 3

Comment: thank you and sorry for not clear requirement,  the expected result is show which column has value = 1

Comment: You have to apply WHERE condition on corresponding column accordingly. If it is Field1, apply WHERE condition as `WHERE Field1 = 1`

Comment: thanks but i think that's not correct, if I add where field1=1 to query, it will show all like  ID =1 , FIeld 1= 1, field2 = 0, field3=1, field4 = 0, but the result i want is just only field1 and  field 3 because thier value = 1. it will show the ID with colums that have value  = 1

Comment: select field1, field3 from table1 where Id = 1 and (field1 = 1 and field3 = 1) . Please check this